# Converting xpath from String to WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, pageobjects

Right now I use the below method in my BasePage and I wish to call this method to my other pages.

So in the below method, the parameter is `(String xpathExpression)`, How do I change this to WebElement and use other element locators which will be defined in other pages.

```
protected boolean CheckSorting(String xpathExpression) {
    List<WebElement> issueTypeDropdown = new LinkedList<>(driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathExpression)));
    LinkedList<String> issueTypes = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < issueTypeDropdown.size(); i++) {
        //System.out.println(issueTypeDropdown.get(i).getText());
        issueTypes.add(issueTypeDropdown.get(i).getText());
    }
    return Compare(issueTypes);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the locator from `WebElement`. If you want the locator strategy to be dynamic you can send `By` to the method

```
protected boolean CheckSorting(By by) {
    List<WebElement> issueTypeDropdown = new LinkedList<>(driver.findElements(by));
    //...
}
```

Uses:

```
CheckSorting(By.xpath(xpathExpression));
```

Comment: Thanks you!! But right now for my use, I have defined my element locator as `public @FindBy(xpath = "(//INPUT[@type='search'])[4]/following-sibling::UL") WebElement dropdown_issueType;` in the same page where I am going to use this method . Now how do I use this?

Comment: @moh17 You can't extract the locator from the `Webelement`. If you can't use the page factory to locate the list you need to pass string or `By` as parameter.

Comment: Thanks got it. But it would be helpful if you can guide me on how to use page factory to locate the list.

Comment: @moh17 Like you located single element, just to list `public @FindBy(xpath = "xpath") List<WebElement> elements;`

Comment: Will try this. Can I initiate a chat with you if i need any clarification?

Comment: @moh17 You can try, but soon I won't be available for few days. You can always post a new question.

Comment: Thanks much! Will do